# Should I count time in the company gym as hours worked?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, hours, benefits

I am a programmer, paid hourly. My workplace recently added a gym to its facilities. If I use this gym, should I count it in my hours worked, or discount those hours when reporting?

Comment: Use your lunch break, or go before or after work.  I usually go after meetings because meetings burn me out.

Comment: NO. And if you really want to be 100% sure, take this up as a joke with your manager and see if he/she laughs.

Comment: Upvoted simply because it is a benefit at some companies (as Ramhound indicates in a comment below).  It seems odd to most of us, but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Almost assuredly no.

If there is a liberal policy like foosball tables in the work area so creative people can blow off steam while their minds chug in the background, then maybe.  But you are spending time on something that has no outwardly visible resemblance to your work.  In so doing you are at minimum inviting questions.  By the time it comes to the point of someone asking the question, you can also rest assured they're already annoyed and you're starting your explanation from inside a hole.

If you are set on doing it, I'd at least start with asking your manager.  **edit:**  And if you do, ask the question in a fashion indicating you very much do not expect it to be considered work time.

Comment: Solid answer, and if your not 1000000000% sure, ask your manager.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the company is ultimately managing your time, you're on the clock. If you're managing your time, you're not on the clock. This is why commutes and certain types of "on-call" aren't paid.

Comment: The only exception to this answer, is when the company specifically has a policy, allowing portition of your time to this actviity.  There are typically limitations that surround the policy (no more than x hours per week) or (it must be done at the gum on site).  **Best way to find out if such a policy exists is to simply ask**

Comment: @Ramhound, well said.  I think it's worth calling out, as others have inspired me to edit, this is such an uncommon benefit (paid workouts) that at least a little caution in how the question is posed should be exercised.  A lot of managers would consider it downright offensive to even insinuate their budgets should be paying for what they consider your own personal business.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel - All I know is my employeer has thousands of employees and it's offered to us.

Answer (score 3):

No. Company provided or not unless your work directly involves working out, it would not qualify as working hours. If anything, your employer is providing you with a resource that is otherwise something that would come out of your pocket as a monthly expense.